# Google+ Authentication doesn't work or redirect users - SWIFT

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus, soundcloud, google-authentication, sfsafariviewcontroller

So i'm currently working with the soundcloud api and when i'm trying to authenticate users nothing seems to happen in the SFSafariViewController it's just a blank screen. So after you enter your email and password your presented with this.

[image]

Here is the url as well that is being generated for the screen that it is stuck on

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=984739005367.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=postmessage&response_type=code%20token%20id_token%20gsession&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&state=341196924%7C0.541964801&access_type=offline&request_visible_actions=http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.google.com%2FAddActivity%20http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.google.com%2FListenActivity%20http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.google.com%2FCreateActivity&after_redirect=keep_open&cookie_policy=single_host_origin&include_granted_scopes=true&proxy=oauth2relay575978621&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fsoundcloud.com&&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_GB.I6H28a4S6Q8.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOj1S9HWe2PeOuPxSv4MTMWHY_9jw
```

Comment: Hello Tunds, Did you find the solution for this ? I am also having the same issue